# Decide which model to retrieve data on Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a simple API which should do the following:

A user makes a request on /getContent endpoint, with the geographical coordinates for this user. By content, it means audio files.

Every time they send a request, we should just get a random object from a Model and return the URL field from it, to be consumed by the front end. For this, it can be a random one, it doesn't matter much which one.

Also, we should keep tracking about the requests each user makes. This way, we can check how many requests the user has made, and when they were made.

Every 5 requests or so, the idea is to send the user a customized content based on their location. My idea is to store this content in another model, since it would have many more fields in comparison from the standard content.

Basically, at every request, I'd check if it's time to send a special content. If not, just send the random one. Otherwise, I'd check if the time is appropriate, and the user is within a valid location based on the special content's data in the model. If this validation passes, we send the URL of the special content, otherwise, we just send the random one.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to design this. My initial idea is to have two different models:

Model 1: Standard content. It has some fields to its meta data, such as duration, title and other stuff like this.

Model 2: Custom content. Besides the meta data, it should contain the geographical data, and the datetime range. This will allow the checking to be made if the content should be played or not.

Now it's the part I'm pretty much clueless. How to make it all work together?

QUESTIONS

1. Maybe storing every single request data from every user, and checking this data might not be very effective. It would require some writing at every request instead of just reading.
2. Since I'd be using two different models, how can I make the decision to happen in the view? I mean, the final output would be the same, an URL. But I'd have to make the decision process to happen in the view on which model to use.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: There's many ways to go about it, but there's really nothing too complicated about it. Why are you stuck? A view is just a function, it's not related to one particular model. And you'll have to keep track of a user's activity somehow. If this all happens in a session, you could use the session, otherwise just use another model. I'd say, start writing code and when you face  particular issue, ask a question.

Comment: Note that a DRF class-based view might not be the right type of view, you can always write a simple function view yourself.